# How to query by missing relationship in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

Is it possible in GraphQL to query for records missing a certain relationship?

E.g.

```
Type Foo
  - id
Type Bar
  - id
  - foo_id
```

How can I search for Foo which don't have any Bar associated?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

```
query FooMissingBar {
  foo(where: { _not: { bar: {} } }) {
    id
  }
}
```